# Got error while creating database in postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql

I want to create user and database in linux server. 
I am able to create user with the following code:

```
su - postgres
# createuser -S -D -R myUser
```

but when I tried to create database with code :

```
# createdb -U myUser -p 5432 myDatabase
```

I get following error:

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "myUser"
```

I am new to linux so I am unable to figure out why I was able to create user but while creating database there is connection error with postgres. And also error for ident
authentication for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn more about HBA configuration.

There are some basic authentication methods:

- **trust** - every users can connect to database(s) specified at second column where all means just all databases in cluster (yeah, excluding template0, because datallowconn in pg_database system catalog is set to false.. nevermind)
- **ident** (prior to PostgreSQL 8.4 ident sameuser) - only actually logged (for example using su in console as your `su - postgres`) system user (with same name as role name) can connect
- **md5** - every user that knows role (PostgreSQL) password can log to database

Every time you attempting connection to concrete **role** and **database** even if do not write is explicitely.

The are generally two types of connection:

- **local** - Unix-domain sockets
- **host** - using TCP/IP connection

If you don't know which you are using, then it's local. To use TCP/IP connection you need to specify -h option with target IP where postmaster is listening. For example you can add -h localhost or -h 127.0.0.1, but check your listen_adresses (AFAIK default value is localhost, so it's ok) property in postgresql.conf and accepted client IP-address(es) in HBA.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Answer (score 1):

you must add the auth setting on your

~postgres/VERSION/data/pg_hba.conf

```
e.g: for localhost
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident

e.g: full conf:
local   all             all                                     ident
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             myUser          127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

then reload the postgres